# Macro to select and range, change format, offset then loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have an 2010 Excel sheet with essentially 80 identical "pages" 30 rows each. There is a range of cells starting with "K126:N130" which I need to turn off text wrapping for this range, then repeat for the following 79 "pages" and stop at row 2520
I am unfamiliar with "do until" but here is what I have so far.
Thanks

```
Sub formatchange()
'
' formatchange Macro
'
Range("K126:N130").Select
With Selection
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
End With
ActiveSheet.Range("K126:N130").Offset(30).Select
With Selection
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub formatchange()

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("K126:N130")

    do while rng.cells(1).row < 2520

    With rng
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    End With

    Set rng = rng.offset(30,0)

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: you aswered quickly but not before i copied the string 80 times and changed the offset. my way worked but yours runs much faster! Wow! Thanks